# Mysql get cells based on value

Tags: mysql

I  have the following MySQL database:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d82f

How can i make sure i get the max amount grouped by time?
So i would get:

```
Max(hitId)  |     dte        |  time
    1       |    2015-01-18  | 19:00:00 
    2       |    2015-01-18  | 20:00:00 
    1       |    2015-01-18  | 21:00:00 
    2       |    2015-01-18  | 22:00:00
```

But i dont want to get the previous date.
So only where the date is '2015-01-18' (or whatever i put)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT( hitId ) AS Max_hits, dte AS sDate, TIME AS sTime
FROM hitcounter
WHERE dte =  '2015-01-18'
GROUP BY sTime
ORDER BY sDate ASC
```